# Fractional part of a square root

Tags: number-theory

> Let $a$ be a positive integer and let $\{x\}$ denote the fractional part of $x$. Prove that $\left \{\sqrt{a^2+1}\right \}$ is smaller than any element from the set $S = \{\{\sqrt{x}\}\mid x < a^2 \quad \text{and} \quad \sqrt{x} \not \in \mathbb{Z}\}$.

Intuitively this makes sense. It is basically saying that the larger a number gets, the smaller its fractional part of its square root gets. But how do we prove it?

Comment: Didn't you mean "smaller"?

Comment: @xyzzyz Yes, sorry.

Answer (score 5):

For each $x<a^2$, $\sqrt{x}\notin \mathbb{Z}$, assume $k^2<x<(k+1)^2$, where $1\leqslant k\leqslant a-1$ is an integer. Then $\{\sqrt{x}\}=\sqrt{x}-k\geqslant \sqrt{k^2+1}-k$.

Now, consider $f(x)=\sqrt{x^2+1}-x=\frac{(\sqrt{x^2+1}-x)(\sqrt{x^2+1}+x)}{\sqrt{x^2+1}+x}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+1}+x}$, which is strictly decreasing.

Thus, we have $\{ \sqrt{a^2+1} \}=\sqrt{a^2+1}-a=f(a)<f(k)<\sqrt{k^2+1}-k\leqslant \{x\}$.